# 100% auto height on iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an iframe on my page, i am using this code:

```
<script>
    function autoResizeiFrame(obj) {
        obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
    }
    </script>
    <iframe src="link.php" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" onload='javascript:autoResizeiFrame(this);'></iframe>
```

which automatically resizes the iframe to 100% height.

This works fine, however if the browser is re-sized, making the screen width smaller i can see the iframe borders and it does not automatically re-size the height of the iframe.

It's only re-sizing it on page load

Comment: exactly. you're not specifying it to do on window resize. what's the question? lol

Comment: Accept one of the answers please. The first would be the fairest

Comment: @TimRijckaert I will accept an answer if you give me a chance. And correct, the first would be the fairest, yours was at 21:29:16 and the other from Federico was at 21:28:36, so guess which one i will mark as the answer :)

Comment: I was not implying you should mark mine as THE answer. I was simply wondering why it took you so long. Still Frederico's post is not marked as answer. :')

Comment: its only been 1 hour :)

Comment: But we answered seconds after asking. :')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you should use the resize event:

I have updated the solution:

If I understand correctly you wont the content of the iframe to not scroll and allays display in full .... than this will work... (i hope...)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function autoResizeiFrame(obj) {
    obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
}

window.addEventListener("load",function(){
    var obj=document.getElementById("myIframe");
    obj.contentWindow.addEventListener("resize",function(){autoResizeiFrame(obj);},false);
    autoResizeiFrame(obj);
},false);
</script>

<iframe id="myIframe" src="index.php" frameborder="3" width="100%" height="100%" style="border:2px solid red;"></iframe>
```

Let me know.

Comment: can the obj be the frame ID or Class?

Comment: obj is the iframe element ... "autoResizeiFrame" is your function... give the Iframe an id and then call autoResizeiFrame(document.getElementById("id_of_Iframe"));

Comment: ok thats resizing the iframe, but its constanrly making the page longer

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the `onresize` event on your page. See this link. [W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onresize.asp)

```
window.addEventListener("resize", autoResizeiFrame(document.getElementById("myframe")));
```

Comment: can the obj be the frame ID or Class?

Comment: Looking at your code you need a DOM object. So: document.getElementById("myframe");

Comment: You could also use getElementByTag

Comment: just tried this http://pastebin.com/yiFx5Mcb but its not resizing the iframe at all